# Can't display $_ENV Values

Tags: php, html-table, environment-variables

I'm using Putty.  I am trying to get `$_ENV`to print to a table.  I seem to be OK with `$_SERVER` displaying, but everything I try with `$_ENV` wont display.  My code is :

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>$_ENV</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>
<TABLE border="1">
<TR><TD><b>Keys</b><TD><b>Values</b>
<?php
while (list ($key, $value) = each($_ENV)) {
  print ("<TR><TD>$key<TD>$value\n");
}
?>
</TABLE>
</BODY></HTML>
```

The `getenv("REMOTE_ADDR")` and `print_r($_ENV)` will only give me the Remote Address.  I want all keys and their variables.  For `$_SERVER` my code gives me all keys from a form that's submitted.

```
<?php
//If form not submitted, display form.
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

    $msg = $_POST["msg"];
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $posts = file_get_contents("posts.txt");
    $posts = "$msg - $name\n" . $posts;
    file_put_contents("posts.txt", $posts);
    echo $posts;

    print"<table border=1>";
         echo "<th>Keys</th> <th>My SERVER Info</th>";
 foreach ($_SERVER as $key=>$val )
         {
         echo "<tr><td>".$key."</td><td>" .$val."</tr>";
         }
    print"</table>";
```

Comment: Why don't you do `print_r($_ENV);` before the loop and see what's in there.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your `$_ENV` is empty , just add `getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");` before your `while` and see it magically working.

I suggested `getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");` for an example...

Like this..

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>$_ENV</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>
<TABLE border="1">
    <TR><TD><b>Keys</b><TD><b>Values</b>
            <?php
            getenv("REMOTE_ADDR"); //<--- Add here
            while (list ($key, $value) = each($_ENV)) {
                print ("<TR><TD>$key<TD>$value\n");
            }
            ?>
</TABLE>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: But I want all ENV variables, not just REMOTE_ADDR

Answer (score 0):

For `getenv()` to work, php configuration parameter `variables_order` must contain 'E'. If not, you must call getenv() for each value that you may want to have. Doing that will also add it to the $_ENV array.

Alternatively, you could parse the `phpinfo()` results. To make it only return environment information, you could use:

```
phpinfo(INFO_ENVIRONMENT);
//Or also, as INFO_ENVIRONMENT is just a constant with the value 16
phpinfo(16);
```

Also, I really suggest you to use `foreach` instead of while-list-each. It's really MUCH faster, easier to read and isn't influenced by the cursor, so you are more error-proof without having to reset() first.

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
}
```